# How can I combine 2 rows to 1 row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data like this:

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pink |
| 1 | Blue |
| 2 | Red |
| 2 | Green |

I want it to look like this:

| ID | Color1 | Color2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pink | Blue |
| 2 | Red | Green |

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does the original order of Color1/Color2 matter? There doesn't seem to be any identifier for preserving an ordinal position. Is there a unique record identifier somewhere? What you have there appears to be a group identifier.

Comment: The original order does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a known, or maximum number of columns a simple PIVOT or conditional aggregation should do the trick, otherwise, you would need Dynamic SQL

**Example PIVOT**

```
Select *
 From  ( Select ID
               ,Col = concat('Color',row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID)
               ,Val = Color
         From  YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot (max(Val) for Col in ([Color1]
                            ,[Color2]
                            ) 
       ) pvt
```

**Example Conditional Aggregation**

```
Select ID
      ,Color1 = max(case when RN=1 then Color end )
      ,Color2 = max(case when RN=2 then Color end )
 From (
        Select ID
              ,Color
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID)
         From  YourTable
      )  A
 Group By ID
```

**Note:**

The `order by ID` portion in `row_number()` could be any other column like `Color` ascending or descending.